# How can I testfor a nearby player in minecraft 1.13

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Have been searching a couple of hours now just so I can find out how I can testfor a nearby player... One thing I noticed is that testfor doesn't even work anymore so whats the deal with that? I have been using /testfor @a[r=5] but yeah, not anymore...

Answer (score 1):

`r` and `rm` have now become a **range** called `distance`. For example:

- `@a[distance=..5]` selects people 5 meters or closer
- `@a[distance=2..6]` selects people 2 to 6 meters away
- `@a[distance=7..]` select people 7 meters or further away

---

The replacement for `testfor` depends on what you were using it for, but the closest equivalent for most cases would be `execute if entity`. For example:

```
execute if entity @a[distance=..3] run say Someone is within 3 blocks!
```

Comment: Well, apparantly the commands were all working, but me being me I didn't toggle "always active"